# Auto-switching Power Mux with High Current Output for 5V Power Sources

Tags: circuit-design, design, power-electronics

I'm trying to find a power mux or design a circuit to supply 5V to a load that draws approximately 6A. The power supply should have a back-up power which is why a battery will be used alongside an AC-DC converter; should the converter fail, the battery will take over. The setup looks something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f456Z6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, both converters output 5 Volts and both are capable of outputting the amount of current I need. The crux of the system is the power multiplexer. Although it was pointed out to me that I can use TPS211x as power mux, they're limited in terms of current rating and output only 1.25 or 2 A depending on the version.

I was thinking of using them in parallel to output higher current, but am not sure about any consequences resulting from that. One thing I'd like to point out to is that the load can be divided into 3 parts each of which would need 5V, 2A to operate. I'd appreciate any comments on that.

Is there any breakout board that I can use to do this switching? I'm open to using diodes, but only concerned with the voltage drop. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
After getting in touch with the technical support, it was pointed out to me that using 2 units of TPS211x in parallel can be risky if the switching time in the two components is different.

Answer (score 1):

Use can two schottky diodes, and a SPDT relay. In this way, during the relay switch time, the output voltage won't drop too much, without needing a big capacitor. Once the contact has been established, you get a very low voltage drop, and no dissipation on the diodes.

Remember that relays have different ratings between NO and NC contacts. The NC contact have smaller ratings.

I guess that you can use diodes with smaller ratings than 6A, as they just operate for a very small time (check the datasheet for peak forward current!).

Alternatively, you could use an hysteretic comparator, which drives two MOSFETs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLOT3c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That's an interesting method. What I've seen is similar in concept but with mosfets: using the parasitic diode within the mosfet in the same way as your schottkys and then energising the fet to bypass in the same was as the relay.

Comment: Looks like a pretty darn neat solution! So, let me see if I get it straight: 5V "from mains" is connected to NO while COM is connected to 5V out. Mains will keep the relay energized leading to 2 things: 1) relay switch will be closed, as a result of which, 2) current will flow through the switch at which point Schottky diodes will be closed. When the mains power fails, relay jumps to NC position at which point current flows from battery. Are the diodes meant for current flowing between 5V "from mains" and battery?

Comment: There won't be any current between "5V from mains" and "5V from battery" (diodes are back to back). The schottky diodes are needed so that, when the relay is switching (i.e. the contact is neither connected to the NC nor to the NO), the "5V out" will drop **at most** by the forward voltage drop of one diode: about 0.5V for a high current Schottky diode. This drop will last just for few ms (until the relay contact is closed to NC or NO)

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions?

Why don't use use what is called an "electromagnetic relay"? When AC power is on, it will route power from the 5 volt converter to the load. When AC is removed, the relay will de-energize to switch the power source to come from the battery.

You might need a 100 uF "hold-up" capacitor as the relay switches from AC sourced power to battery power (just a few milli seconds).

Of course, it could all be done with MOSFETs with a little more complication but if a "relay" works why do anything else?

Comment: There's a concern I've got since I'm not very familiar with the relays. If the converter is down, relay allows dc source to take over. If the AC power is up and running, would relay allow the converter to take over? Is the transition time fast enough?

Comment: The transition time is usually less than 10 milli seconds so you need to "hold-up" the voltage with a capacitor during the time that battery disconnects and the AC power supply takes over.

Comment: 10 ms, 6A, 100uF => The capacitor gets totally discharged (I*t/C yields 600V...). To have a 10% drop in 10ms, you should install a 0.12F capacitor...). Even with a 100us turn-on time, the capacitor will be discharged.